# animation issue by toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css

while am clicking the click button the container 3 disappears and it appears again when clicked, during this, transition between container 3 and continer 4 there is a white gap occurs and disappears. how to fix it.

http://jsfiddle.net/wxab9Ldn/16/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var evenH = 0;
    $('.row .small-4').each(function(){
        var getH = $(this).outerHeight();
        if(getH > evenH)
            evenH = getH;
    });
    $('.row .small-4').css({'height':evenH});

    var slider_width = $('.pollSlider').width();
    $("button").click(function () {
        var effect = 'slide';
        var options = {
            direction: 'left'
        };
        var duration = 700;
        $('.delet').toggle(effect, options, duration);
        //$('.popUp').addClass("popUp2");
        if ($(this).css("margin-right") == slider_width + "px" && !$(this).is(':animated')) {
            $('.pollSlider,button').animate({
                "margin-right": '-=' + slider_width
            }, 'slow');

        } else {
            if (!$(this).is(':animated')) //perevent double click to double margin
            {
                $('.pollSlider,button').animate({
                    "margin-right": '+=' + slider_width
                }, 'slow');

            }
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Any how if we are going with margin property using jQuery animation we will have some white space and the same we can also achive with toggling width. Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/wxab9Ldn/17/)

```
$('button').click(function() {    
    $(".delet").animate({width:'toggle'},350);        
})
```

Comment: width should not differs